# Unable to change ngboostrap offcanvas width

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to make the offcanvas in ng-bootstrap wider, but it's not working. Any advice or help is apperciated. TIA.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<ng-template #newoffcanvas let-offcanvas>
        <div class="offcanvas-header bg-primary text-white">
            //some stuff here
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body">
            //some stuff here
        </div>
</ng-template>
```

Here is the original size:

[image]
[image]

I am able to change it using the element selector in developer tools in the browser, like the pictures below:

[image]
[image]

Or if I uncheck this box, it also become bigger too (auto?), which is perfect for me.

For my CSS, I tried a few custom CSS, but doesn't work. I put this in the component SCSS file.

```
  .custom-offcanvas-width {
    --bs-offcanvas-width: 600px !important;
  }
```

HTML

```
<ng-template #newoffcanvas let-offcanvas>
        <div class="offcanvas-header bg-primary text-white custom-offcanvas-width">
            //some stuff here
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas-body custom-offcanvas-width">
            //some stuff here
        </div>
</ng-template>
```

I also tried inline styling, but does not work either.

```
style="--bs-offcanvas-width: auto;"
```

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292950/change-bootstrap-offcanvas-size-via-css-bootstrap-5-2) doesn't work for me... It created a different problem when I added a div surrounding the offcanvas-header and offcanvas-body; my offcanvas doesn't display anything anymor (white screen), and I'm not sure why (different issue somewhere else)...

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

In your CSS, add a class like this:

```css
.wide-panel {
   width: 1000px !important;
}
```

Then in your Angular component, inject the `NgbOffcanvas` service and use the `panelClass` property on `NgbOffcanvasOptions` to set your custom width:

```js
constructor(private offCanvas: NgbOffcanvas) { }

openPanel() {
   this.offCanvas.open(PanelComponent, {
      position: 'end',
      panelClass: 'wide-panel'
    });
}
```

Hope this helps :)

[image]